What is correct way to deal with large amounts in TypeORM?
I am trying to use TypeORM for my app.
I have database structure like, Sack -> Fruit <- FruitType, so, there are sacks, each containing some fruits, and each fruit is specified type.
I tried to do bulk insert naive way:
let fruitEntities = [];
let sackEntities = data.map(sack => {
  let sackEntity = new Sack();
  sackEntity.fruits = sack.map(fruit => CreateFruitEntity());
  fruitEntities = fruitEntities.concat(sackEntity.fruits);
  return sackEntity;
});
await getRepository(Fruit).save(fruitEntities);
await getRepository(Sack).save(sackEntities);

it didnt worked on large amounts. In one test case I have 40K sacks and up to 10 fruits in each. I get message about stack overflow:
"RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded\n    at .../src/persistence/SubjectTopoligicalSorter.ts:91:28\n    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)\n    at SubjectTopoligicalSorter.sort (.../src/persistence/SubjectTopoligicalSorter.ts:87:34)\n    at SubjectExecutor.execute (.../src/persistence/SubjectExecutor.ts:136:11)\n    at EntityPersistExecutor.execute (.../src/persistence/EntityPersistExecutor.ts:182:36)\n    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)\n    

Obviously, naive way cant work, but what is correct one?
I expect it to work in reasonable time, like up to 30 seconds in average Azure S1 environment

Stack overflow? That's unusual. Please [edit] your question to include the exact error message (including stack trace)

Added message, but is approach to bulk insert itself ok? I get this error when saving fruitEntities, only when amounts are large
